# FreeBSD apache folder owner (and future folder owner)

Tags: apache, freebsd

I installed a apache/mysql/php server onto my FreeNAS (FreeBSD) jail. Everything works fine except for when I upload a folder (i.e. Wordpress) I need to set the owner of the folder through SSH.

Is there a way to always set the Apache user to owner of the folder (and future folders - recursively)?

Comment: I understand that when I upload i.e. Wordpress from my root account (through SSH) that the owner isn't the same as the apache owner/group. But is there a way around this or do I have to set the owner/group every single time?

Comment: Is it ok to (for instance) upload files as 'www' user?